# Get the value of a method which is array inside an array

Tags: arrays, vbscript

below is the code on which i am working.

```
Dim OBD
Dim pl
Dim plg()
Set OBD = CreateObject("OBD.OBDManager")
OBD.ConnectDB
If OBD.DBConnected Then
  pl = OBD.CVar(OBD.QueryOBDPolicies(Nothing, "", "", "", "", "", True,2,1))
  For i = LBound(pl) To UBound(pl)
    WScript.Echo pl(i).GetName() & "Version: " & pl(i).GetVersionString()
  Next
End If

Set OBD = Nothing
```

Like `GetName` there is another Method in which I am interested to print the result and this method is an array.

I tried to print simply `pl(i).GetpgList()` like name and version method but here I get the error

> Type Mismatch.

Could some one tell me how can I get it printed along with name and Version?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are returning an Object array it is far easier to iterate through using the `For Each Object In Objects` approach.

As for displaying the result of `GetpgList()` just use the same method you did before to iterate through by index *(or even use another `For Each`, it is entirely up to you)*. Personally with lists because I don't have to create a counter variable I prefer the `For index = ... In ...` approach.

```
Dim OBD
Dim pl, plg
Dim i

Set OBD = CreateObject("OBD.OBDManager")
OBD.ConnectDB
If OBD.DBConnected Then
  pl = OBD.CVar(OBD.QueryOBDPolicies(Nothing, "", "", "", "", "", True,2,1))
  For Each obj In pl
    WScript.Echo obj.GetName() & ", Version: " & obj.GetVersionString()
    plg = obj.GetpgList()
    For i = LBound(plg) To UBound(plg)
      WScript.Echo "Value " & i & ": " & plg(i)
    Next
  Next
End If
Set OBD = Nothing
```

If you don't want to loop through the values and want to return a specific element of the array you can do something like *(if using your existing example code)*;

```
'Result of GetpgList() is assumed to be a 1 dimensional array.
'This example explicitly pulls out the first value.

yourvariable = pl(i).GetpgList()(0)
```

Or using the code example in this answer

```
yourvariable = obj.GetpgList()(0)
```